# Библиотеки для работы с изображениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy, обработка-изображений

Мне требуется перебрать все пиксели изображения. С помощью каких библиотек я могу это сделать?

Comment: Да, можете. Циклом

Comment: Лол щас очень посмеялся с коммента выше

Comment: @hedgehogues А поподробнее? Какие библиотеки использовать? Вы можете привеcти пример кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько библиотек, которые позволят решить Вашу задачу. Одна из наиболее мощных и соверщенных [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/). Она относительно сложна в установке и требует некоторых навыков работы с системой Unix (Windows) желательно через консоль. Здесь есть большое количетсво функций для обработки изображений. [Пример](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-images-in-python/) работы.

Ещё одна библиотека, которая предназначена для работы с изображениями. Она проще в установке, но менее удобна. Это [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729915/reading-images-in-python) работы.

Следует отметить, что и в том, и в другом случае, изображения можно привести к `numpy.array`.

[Numpy](https://numpy.org/) -- стандартная библиотека, написанная на `C` для эффективной работы с матрицами.

Пример привидения:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im = Image.open('hopper.jpg')
a = np.asarray(im)
```

После этого, Вы сможете перебрать все пиксели изображения примерно так:

```
for i in a:
   for j in a[i]:
      do_smth(a[i][j])
```

Comment: Вообще-то установка OpenCV совсем не сложная, просто ввожу в консоль в Windows ``pip install opencv-python``

Comment: Возможно, в windows что-то отличается. Вероятно, ряд программ заранее предустановлен. Либо, Вы их ранее устанавливали. В Unix требуется установить ещё ряд дополнительных пакетов. Просто воспользоваться `pip install` недостаточно

Comment: Еще один вопрос, когда я использовал пример Вашего кода на PIL, у меня выводило ошибку: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/andre/PycharmProjects/All/PILLOW1.py", line 8, in <module>
    do_smth(a[i][j])
NameError: name 'do_smth' is not defined```. Что делать?

Comment: Это пример. Замените `do_smth` на Вашу логику.